# jQuery draggable revert and stop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

First question, so be kind :)

What I am trying to do is call a function when the user releases the draggable, and before the revert animation has completed.

As far as I can see, the stop event is called only when the revert has finished. I have tried passing a function to the revert option of draggable, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a bit of my code to demonstrate;

```
$("a").draggable({
    helper:function(){
        return $("<div/>",{id:"mydrag",text:"link"}).appendTo("body");
    },
    revert:function(evt,ui){
        // $("#mydrag").fadeOut("slow");
        return true;
    },
    stop:function(evt,ui){
        console.log("fin");
    }
});
```

If I uncomment the first line of the revert function - fadeout - then the element fades out but does not revert. The console only logs "fin" when the revert animation has completed.

Can anyone help me? Needless to say I have Googled a lot for an answer, but with no luck.

Buster

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, according to [this blog](http://www.agilepro.com/mod_geek/javascript/jquery-ui-draggable-revert-callback/), the undocumented `revert` callback only takes a single argument (the drop socket object, or the boolean `false` if the drop was rejected).

Now, the problem is that `draggable` uses `animate()` internally to reposition the helper. Apparently, that animation gets queued and only starts after your `fadeOut` effect finishes.

One way to achieve what you want is to perform the call to `animate()` yourself, like this:

```
revert: function(socketObj) {
    if (socketObj === false) {
        // Drop was rejected, revert the helper.
        var $helper = $("#mydrag");
        $helper.fadeOut("slow").animate($helper.originalPosition);
        return true;
    } else {
        // Drop was accepted, don't revert.
        return false;
    }
}
```

That allows the draggable helper to fade out while it's being reverted.

You can test that solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pNwm9/).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I wonder why the revert callback remains undocumented? In fact, I wonder why the jquery UI documentation in general is so poor compared to jquery core. Thanks again!

Comment: your on the right track, but calling originalPosition literally returns nothing, even with your jsfiddle. Not sure where you found this part because calling .animate(undefined) essentially does nothing. The revert animation is actually still a result of returning true from within your callback function. So basically, what your code is doing is simply bypassing the 'queueing' of the animation, allowing it to run simultaneously with whatever other animation you choose to put in your callback function followed by returning true. Conclusion: remove this .animate($helper.originalPosition);

Comment: @Mike, you're absolutely right, `$helper.originalPosition` is indeed `undefined` during the `revert` event. However, removing the call to `animate(undefined)` results in the item not reverting and fading out "in place". There is definitely something shady here...